# cv2.adaptiveThreshold() returns empty matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
    # Read image in grayscale mode
img = cv2.imread(inp_pic,0)

    # Median Blur and Gaussian Blur to remove Noise
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,3)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
print(img)

    # Adaptive Threshold for handling lightning
im_th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,5)
print(im_th)
```

The function adaptive threshold returns an empty matrix here but the image being passed(img) is not an empty matrix (i checked using the print statement) Why is it so ?

You can find the source code here :
https://github.com/tanmay-edgelord/HandwrittenDigitRecognition/blob/master/performRecognition.ipynb

Comment: Can you post the picture?

Comment: Added to the repository

Comment: Are you referring `[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]` as an empty matrix ?

Comment: Yes because the roi matrix  'roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]' in my code (line number 49) is an empty matrix which means that the findContours function failed to find any contours in the image. Why is it happening ?

Comment: So the code you've posted here is not what's causing the problem? Please post a [mcve] here, not on an external site.

Comment: The main problem was that resize function in the for loop was reporting a null image and I thought that this is because the threshold matrix is empty so I think I provided a good explanation of the problem I though I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code on the on the image at https://github.com/tanmay-edgelord/HandwrittenDigitRecognition/blob/master/Digit1.jpg and it worked as expected. The only change I made was to display the image using `cv2.imshow()`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
    # Read image in grayscale mode
img = cv2.imread(r"path\to\img",0)

    # Median Blur and Gaussian Blur to remove Noise
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,3)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
#print(img)

    # Adaptive Threshold for handling lightning
im_th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,5)
cv2.imshow("te", im_th)
if cv2.waitKey():
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Why are you certain this is an empty matrix? This is a pretty large array if you're just judging from `[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]`. Python just displays this as a shorthand version of the array. Just use `np.maximum(img_th)` to get the max value in the array and you will see that the max value is non-zero.

Comment: Was the code successfully able to recognise the digits ? Did the for - loop run successfully ? The main problem was that resize function in the for loop was reporting a null image and I thought that this is because the threshold matrix is empty.

Comment: I posted the resulting image. No errors were reported.
Hope this answered your posted question